# Handling DNS Resolution Failure after Releasing the Primary Public IP on Linux Machine with Multiple IPs

Tags: networking, dns, aws, router, failover

I am encountering an issue on my Linux machine with multiple network interfaces and IP addresses. Specifically, after releasing the primary public IP (let's call it 112. * .* .1) on the ens3 interface, DNS resolution fails.

Upon investigating, I found that the default route's source IP (via ip route) remains unchanged in the routing table. Consequently, DNS queries attempt to use the outdated source IP (112. * .* .1), leading to a temporary failure in name resolution.

I am seeking guidance on how to ensure proper DNS resolution after releasing the primary public IP. Is there a recommended configuration or an automated mechanism to handle this scenario and update the default route's source IP accordingly?

**Additional Information:**

Operating System:

```
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 
 Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-42-generic
 Network Configuration Tool: Netplan
```

DNS Resolution Failure:

```
root@ecsb6285de3e605:~#  ping -I  112. *.* .2  www.amazon.com 
ping: www.amazon.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

root@ecsb6285de3e605:~# ping -I  112. *.* .2  8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 112. *.* .1 : 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=3.08 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=3.10 ms
```

Network Configurations:

Output of ip route:

```
root@ecsb6285de3e605:~# ip r 
default via 112.73.32.1 dev ens3 proto static 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.105.2.1 dev ens2 proto static 
10.105.2.0/24 dev ens2 proto kernel scope link src 10.105.2.195 
112.*.*.*/19 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 112.*.*.*
```

Output of ip a:

```
root@ecsb6285de3e605:~#  ip a 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:f7:f1:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.105.2.195/24 brd 10.105.2.255 scope global ens2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fef7:f15c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:8f:fc:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 112.*.*.1/19 brd 112.*.*.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.*.*.2/19 brd 112.*.*.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.*.*.3/19 brd 112.*.*.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.*.*.4/19 brd 112.*.*.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 112.*.*.5/19 brd 112.*.*.255 scope global secondary ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Phenomenon:
After releasing the primary IP (112. * . * .1), DNS resolution fails. However, even after releasing 112. * . * .1, there is no change observed in the output of `ip a` or `ip route`.

When explicitly specifying a source IP (e.g., using ip route change default via GATEWAY_IP dev ens3 proto static src Unreleased_EIP), DNS resolution functions as expected.

Upon successful DNS resolution, the default route used is:

```
default via GATEWAY_IP dev ens3 proto static src 112.*.*.2
```

The src address can be any unreleased Elastic IP (EIP).

Comment: The "default route's source IP (via ip route) remains unchanged" shouldn't happen. That is the real problem and DNS is secondary. I connected to Ethernet and WiFi and have 2 default + 2 local routes in `ip r`, and when I disabled each, the corresponding 1 + 1 routes disappeared. What Ubuntu version? NetworkManager, netplan.io or systemd-networkd? What's the full output of `ip r ; ip a` before and after?

Comment: I have included new additional information in the problem description.

Comment: Which command are you using for "releasing the primary public IP"?

Comment: I release the primary public IP by utilizing the 'Unbind EIP' button in the cloud console,  This action severs the binding relationship between the EIP and the host's network interface ip.

Comment: I found that the IP information registered by the network card was not deleted from the network configuration file after unbinding EIP

Comment: At least Amazon's EIP impl. recommends "To avoid unexpected behavior, ensure that all active connections to the resource named in the existing association are closed before you make the change." If you need a workaround, you can try routing the fallback 8.8.4.4 DNS onto the other interface